# How to reverse the drop down selection when user decides not to change the selection in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a drop down button and macro assigned to it. Upon selection of option from drop down the macro asks user whether he/she wants to make the change. If user selects yes code runs successfully. If user selects no the code ends. But the drop down selection changes to the new value which user selected. I want to reflect the old selection before user opted not to effect the change.
Here is how it works.

Step 1 - Proposal Origin is NA

Step 2 - User changes it to LA. But in the confirmation window opts "No".

Step 3 - Since in step 2 user selected "No" nothing happened. But the selection shows Proposal Origin as LA.

I want to keep it as NA when user selects "No" in conformation window.

[image]

Here is the code I have

```
Sub Dropdown6_BeiÄnderung()
'Dropbox Location

Dim Update As Integer


DropVal = Range("L18").Value
Update = MsgBox("You have selected " & Cells(18, 12) & " as Proposal Location. This will reset the Labor sheets. Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo, vbDefaultButton1)
If Update = vbYes Then
        Worksheets("NA-Hours").Range("C8").Value = 0
        Worksheets("LA-Hours").Range("C8").Value = 0
        Worksheets("EU-Hours").Range("C8").Value = 0
        Worksheets("MEA-Hours").Range("C8").Value = 0
        Worksheets("AP-Hours").Range("C8").Value = 0
        
        For i = 17 To 21
            SName = Cells(i, 16).Value
            If Cells(i, 17).Value = 1 Then
            Worksheets(SName).Visible = True
            Else: Worksheets(SName).Visible = False
            End If
        Next
Else
me.Drop Down 6.text = DropVal
 End If
End Sub
```

Need help on the else part to reflect the earlier selection which is stored in variable DropVal.

Comment: The combo-box is in a userform?  `me.Drop Down 6.text = DropVal`

Comment: Think of it: Somewhere an old version must be retained in order to not disturb the new version before it's accepted. Hence: Take a copy of the workspace and work from there. If the user cancels you just drop the workspace. If the user clicks ok, you update the original workspace.

Comment: You cannot use a drop down name with spaces. Then, this object does not return directly its value and also cannot receive a new value. It must have a `ListFillRange` property and your code must act on it. I will try posting a small example to make more relevant what I tried explaining in words...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, look at the next code example in order to understand how a `Drop Down` object value can be handled:

```
Sub handleDropDown()
  Dim dd As DropDown, rngDL As Range, DropVal As String
  
  Set dd = ActiveSheet.DropDowns("Drop Down 6")
  Set rngDL = ActiveSheet.Range(dd.ListFillRange)
  DropVal = "Test" 'use here what you need
  Debug.Print dd.value            'it returns the index of the selected item in ListFillRange range
  Debug.Print rngDL(dd.value)     'it returns the drop down value
  rngDL.cells(dd.value) = DropVal 'it set/change the drop down value, but changing the cell in the range
End Sub
```

What I tried showing is to change the drop down object value. I must confess I am not sure that I understand what "to reverse the drop down selection" should mean...

The drop down value can be changed only if `DropVal` is part of the drop down `ListFillRange` and it was the previous selection. In such a case, the next approach should work.

Practically, you should implement the next code inside your `Else` part of the code:

```
Dim dd As DropDown, rngDL As Range, mtch As Long

  Set dd = ActiveSheet.DropDowns("Drop Down 6")
  Set rngDL = ActiveSheet.Range(dd.ListFillRange)
  'If Range("L18").Value = "NA" the drop down value will become "NA"
  mtch = Application.match(DropVal, rngDL, 0)' position/index of DropVal
  If Not IsError(mtch) Then
      dd.value = mtch
  Else
        MsgBox DropVal & " could not be found in " & rngDL.Address
  End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much FeneDuru. Your worked perfect. The only change I did is that when user opts to change the location I stored the location in separate cell which allowed me to refer the earlier selection. So when user changes the location and opts not to execute the change dropdown is set to the previous selection.